# MYSQL Inner Join as Multiple Rows Result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables on my Database: Menu and Dishes. ( I've translated the columns and database name, don't bother if doesn't make sense )

Menu Table

```
id     date_begins       date_ends      id_dishes_monday  id_dishes_tuesday  id_wednesday              
 1        xxxxx             xxxxx              1                   2                3
```

Dishes Table

```
id      date               dynamic_dishes
 1      2016/03/02              BLOB
 2      2016/03/03              BLOB
 3      2016/03/04              BLOB
```

I wanted to SELECT the id_dishes_monday, id_dishes_tuesday, id_wednesday From Menu Table  and retrieve multiple rows from Dishes Table.

I'm made an attempt using this QUERY but it return only one row and I don't know why.

```
SELECT D.* FROM Menu M INNER JOIN Dishes D WHERE D.id IN (M.id_dishes_monday,M.id_dishes_tuesday,id_dishes_wednesday) ORDER BY M.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**What this Query Produces in this Example**:

```
 id      date               dynamic_dishes
 1      2016/03/02              BLOB
```

**What I want:**

```
     id      date               dynamic_dishes
     1      2016/03/02              BLOB
     2      2016/03/03              BLOB
     3      2016/03/04              BLOB
```

Note that the tables datas are just for exemplification, I'd like to know why this Query didn't worked as well the correct Query for it.

Comment: "don't bother if doesn't make sense" - ok

Comment: I mean to not pay attention to the database or columns names and only on the logic even if they doesn't make sense for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are limiting your output!

```
SELECT D.* 
FROM Menu M
INNER JOIN Dishes D
WHERE D.id IN (M.id_dishes_monday,M.id_dishes_tuesday,id_dishes_wednesday)
ORDER BY M.id DESC
```

I've deleted the LIMIT 1 at the end of your query, which limit the result to the first row

Comment: That was it. I was thinking that the limiter was for the Menu table and did not noticed that. Thanks

Comment: This is really a CROSS JOIN - but MySQL doesn't care about such subtleties.